# Browser crashes on heavy single page pplication

Tags: javascript, crash, single-page-application, crash-reports

We have a big single page application, that started to crash from time to time. We were trying to debug it for a while now, but unfortunately, still no results. We used traditional debugging tools, but they were not very useful - perhaps not used correctly.

The app seems to crash most often on Safari, it doesn't crash that often in Chrome, but it still does, so I can't rule out a problem with browser(s).

I have managed to get this crash report, which you can find at the end of this question, unfortunately I don't know what to look for in it. I know it's huge and I'm just throwing it at you saying "here, find a bug", but could you possibly have a look at it and give me some hint what might be wrong or what should I focus on in the report?

Here is the crash report http://pastebin.com/bNxpuS6T

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered fixing your page instead? I.e. don't make it huge. Or even better don't make it a single page? Also what is the link of the page?

Comment: Yes, it is not possible. The requirement for it is to be SPA, and it has lot of functionalities, therefore it is huge. The page is not accessible to public at the moment, so, unfortunately, I can't provide you with any link

Comment: How does it crash? What kinds of things are you doing to make it crash?

Comment: Strangely enough, it crashes whenever the tab is idle, when I'm not focused in it. When I'm working with it, it doesn't crash (or much rarely than when it's idle)

Answer (score 2):

What I can see from the crash report and the source code is that your JavaScript code was trying to destroy some DOM objects while still iterating through those, which is the reason of the crash.

I guess you may want to check if any timer associated with the idle tabs is still active.

DETAILS:
The WebKit crashed at

```
  1   com.apple.WebCore   0x00007fff83cace2d WebCore::ScriptExecutionContext::willDestroyActiveDOMObject(WebCore::ActiveDOMObject*) + 45
```

where the source code is ([click here](https://github.com/adobe/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/dom/ScriptExecutionContext.cpp))

```
void ScriptExecutionContext::willDestroyActiveDOMObject(ActiveDOMObject* object)
{
    ASSERT(object);
    if (m_iteratingActiveDOMObjects)
        CRASH();
    m_activeDOMObjects.remove(object);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't expect any answer after this long time and this one actually helped. However, I 'm not sure about the time - what kind of timer associated with the idle tabs do you mean? Are you talking about a javascript timer?

Comment: @user1680977 By timer, I meant something like "setTimeout(function(){...}, 3000);".